# How to make an automatically running Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been searching around for the past few days for a way to have my extension run automatically; It works when I use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener but I want it to run without having to manually enable it. I'm thinking my manifest.json is configured wrong for this task. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Rocket",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Feast",

  "icons": {
    "128" : "icon.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon8.png"
  },

  "background": { "page": "background.html" },
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [ "contentscript.js", "jquery-2.1.1.js", "background.js"]
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't most extensions run automatically on startup?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, which is why I'd like to add that same functionality to the extension I'm developing.

Comment: The extensions do indeed start automatically. Any top-level code in `background.js` will execute. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: You said `It works when I use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` ... how would it work if it hadn't been executed in the first place? I suppose this code was part of background.js, so it executed automatically

Comment: What does your extension do?  Should it modify every page?  Should it take an action when they click the browser action?

Comment: What are the contents of the background.js? Is it javascript that executes inline? Or is there some initialization function that needs to be called? Without seeing what is happening in there, it seems like you might need to call an unload handler for your background page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener to 'start' the program you might want to use setInterval() in your javascript instead and it will have your code run every X milliseconds. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Edit: I just found this on the Google support site.
"Please prefer [event pages] to persistent background pages whenever possible for new development and begin migrating existing background pages to this new model. "https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition